# How to make return line in cells in ag-grid without using a cell-renderer?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In this column:
[image]
I would like to return to the line with every new bullet point like this:

[image]
Here's the column definition:

```
{
      headerName: "Vulnerability",
      field: "vulnerability",
      cellClass: "cell-wrap-text"
    }
```

And here's the row definition:

```
 {
      securitycause:'Deliberate action',riskid:'R01 ',operationalrisk:'Improper or fraudulent activity (except reporting)',riskstatements:'Improper or fraudulent activity (except reporting)',businessline:'Informatique',threat:'Inadequate design and planning (including error in implementing security mechanism, software development flaws, insufficient capacity planning)',vulnerability:'● No or insufficient software testing ● Unnecessary services enabled ● Wrong allocation of access rights ● Lack of change control procedure ● Lack of monitoring mechanisms  ● Inadequate recruitment procedures'
    }
```

Is there anyway to do this natively in ag-grid without having to set-up a cellRenderer and using html?
Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use `cellRenderer`?

Comment: @Saksham I can but it makes dealing with the grid a bit more complicated. So I don't want to use it just for the sake of simplicity and clean code

Comment: looks like there is no other way

Comment: @Saksham that's strange. How can I suggest this to ag-grid developers?